# Quem or quid when asking what something is buying?

Tags: grammar-choice, gender, interrogative

I am not sure whether to say "Quem emit Iulius?" or "Quid emit Iulius?" if I want to know what Julius is buying. I know the interrogative pronoun should be in the accusative case but it is not clear to me what gender it should be. As far as I understand it should be the gender of the word that represents what Julius is buying, but if I knew what that was I would not need to ask the question. Is it grammatically correct to use either?

Comment: It shouldn't literally be in the gender of the word for what he is buying.  After all, you may know he is buying a *res*, which is feminine, but you would still use the neuter *quid*, whereas *quam* as an interrogative would specifically refer to a female human being.  This is very different from *quam* as a feminine relative pronoun, which very well can refer to *res* (and any other noun of feminine gender)..

Comment: @CMonsour The word *res* is a red herring for this question. If you ask "what is he buying?", the interrogative is simply *quid*, as neuter is used for general things. The word *res* only plays any role if you ask "what thing is he buying?" with *quam rem*. Romans don't seem to have used *res* quite the same way as modern anglophones use "thing"; I would even say that Julius is buying a thing but not a *res*.

Comment: @CMonsour Ah. I thought pronouns in Latin always took the gender of the word to which they refer. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta If I want to say something like "Put it on the table", and "it" refers to an item which is known, should the pronoun be the gender of the item (as it would be in German) or always "id"?

Comment: @user1488 They do, when they refer to a word.  Demonstrative and relative pronouns do refer to words (usually).  Interrogative and indefinite pronouns do not.

Comment: @user1488 If you refer to a specific thing and you have a word in mind for it, you use the gender of that word for "it". For example: "Habes clavem meam. **Eam** mihi da!" When you have no word in mind (especially if it isn't anything specific), then go with neuter. You can think of the neuter as a backup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the thing being bought is just some thing, then the correct gender is neuter.
It is used for things of unspecific gender, whereas masculine would be used for people of unspecific gender.

If you use *quem*, you are asking **whom** Julius is buying.
Unless he is shopping for slaves, go with *quid* to ask **what** he is buying.
If it could be slaves or something else, then it is a general thing and you should go with neuter.

Comment: I took the question as asking whether to use *quem* or *quid* if you don't know whether he is shopping for slaves.  Similarly, one might ask whether you need masculine plural, neuter plural, or two pronouns to refer to a group that includes both people and things.

Comment: Could you actually say *quem aut quid*?  Or, *quos vel quae*?  Or, in a declarative sentence, *eos et ea*?

Comment: @CMonsour If it could be either way, then the neuter is your choice. Just like in English you can ask "what are you buying?" and your friend can respond "slaves". I would only list both *quem* and *quid* if you specifically want to emphasize that Julius might be buying either slaves or other things. Under normal circumstances I'd go with just neuter.